# Differences in download of r-packages between "conda install" and "install.packages"

Tags: conda

Recently, I used R on Linux, and failed to download some packages with some ERROR messages by `"install.packages"` and `"BiocManager::install"` in R.
Like this:

```
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rgeos’
* removing ‘/home/shpc_100710/miniconda3/envs/R4.0.5/lib/R/library/rgeos’
```

All I think I should do is to `install.packages("rgeos")`. Of cause, there was no use.
But when I turn to Linux environment and downloaded the packages by `"conda install"`, the package was successfully downloaded and library.

So what are the differences in download of r-packages between `"conda install"` and `"install.packages"`? Or Why it's successful in Linux rather than R?

Hope for your reply, thanks.(*^_^*)

Mengfei Wang

Comment: You've provided no OS/release/product details; and only mention Linux.  This is a Ubuntu Q&A site and not SE *Unix & Linux*.  Why ask here?

Comment: Thank you for your question, you are right. I think I should turn to Linux forum. And I got the same trouble when I use differnet OS of ubuntu, so I didn't give the details of OS. I will fill in the details and then ask on Linux forum. Thanks.